# Problem with setting a environment variable

Tags: environment-variables

I want to add Intellij Idea to be able to use `./idea.sh` outside of my bin directory.

I edited my `.bashrc` to add `export PATH=$PATH:/home/xenia/idea-IE-202.7319.78/bin` at the bottom of my file.

Then, I typed `source ~/.bashrc`.

I closed and opened a terminal outside of `/home/xenia/idea-IE-202.7319.78/bin` and I typed `./idea.sh`.

It doesn't work. I gives the error `bash: ./idea.sh: No such file or directory`  I have no idea why. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Prepending `./` tells the shell explicitly *not* to search your `PATH`, but to only look in the current directory `./`

Just type `idea.sh` instead.